# Telegram Bot - Persist Pickle Context across all Users in a Group Chat

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I set out to create a Telegram bot that tracks 'upvote' like functionality in a Group Chat. To try to do this, I adapted the persistentconversationbot.py [code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/persistentconversationbot.py) from the python-telegram-bot package. I got the bot running and managed to deploy it on to Heroku.

Once I invited the bot into a private group chat, I noticed that this approach is only remembering conversations with specific users. I'd like to have the bot remember conversations it has had with all users in a group chat. Would any of you happen to know how I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [explanation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-do-the-per_-settings-in-conversationhandler-do) on the `per_*` parameters of `ConversationHandler`. Note that this is independent of whether your bot uses persistence or not.